# How do I center vertically and horizontally a div inside the body element without absolute positioning?

Tags: css, html, centering

I have read countless Q&A's and blog posts about vertically aligning and centering divs, but I cannot get the simplest case to work: an empty 20x20 div directly in the html body.

html:

```css
 body
    {
        background-color:DarkGray;
        display:table;
    } 

    .box
    {
        background-color:black;

        display:table-cell
        margin:0, auto;    
        
        width:20px;
        height:20px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8At93/382/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325643/how-to-horizontal-vertical-center-a-div

Comment: can someone add a better way for 2020?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`display:table` and `display:table-cell` are bad, stay away from them. Here is a very common way to center a `div` inside `<body>`. It positions the element's top and left sides at the 50% point within `body` and then subtract 1/2 the `width` and `height` from the `margin-top` and `margin-left`.

```css
.box {
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  /* -1/2 width */
  margin-top: -10px;
  /* -1/2 height */
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="box">

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Because you can do everything without them, they were designed to be used for table cells only. One thing that they can do which I don't think you can do without them is center multiple lines of text vertically.

Answer (score 2):

First, there is a syntax error in margin style:

```
margin: 0, auto;
```

But should be:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

With support of vertical positioning it should be:

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: DarkGray;
  height: 100%;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -10px auto;
  /* -height/2 */
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
</body>
```

And there is a discussion on this site [Why not use tables for layout in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html)