# How do i post the content of the div on the middle of the body?

Tags: html, css

**hello i am working in an web applications when i want to  put the grid on the center  my code not work and the grid still on the same place ,
this is what i tried, i am stuck with it  and i did many way but this  that i want i cant get it any help please ?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.grid-container {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: auto auto                 
auto;
grid-gap: 2px;
background-color: #2196F3;
padding: 2px;

}

.items {
background-color: rgba(255, 255,     
255, 0.8);
text-align: center;
padding: 40px 0;




}

.item1 {
grid-column-start: 1;
grid-column-end: 3;
background-color: orange;
}
.item2{
grid-column-start: 3;
grid-column-end: 4;
background-color: orange;

}
.item3{
grid-row-start: 2;
grid-row-end: 4;
background-color:#dfe11b;
}

.item4{
grid-column-start: 2;
grid-column-end: 4;
background-color:#e11b93
}

.item5{
grid-column-start: 2;
grid-column-end: 4;
background-color:#e11b93
}

.item6{

background-color:#0872d4

}
.item7{

background-color:#0872d4
}

.item8{

background-color:#0872d4
}
.Body{
margin: 0;
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
}


</style>
<title>griad</title>
</head>



<body>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1 items"></div>
  <div class="item2 items"></div>
  <div class="item3 items"></div>  
  <div class="item4 items"></div>
  <div class="item5 items"></div>
  <div class="item6 items"></div>
  <div class="item7 items"></div>
  <div class="item8 items"></div>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The output of my code:
[image]

and this is what i want:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I center vertically and horizontally a div inside the body element without absolute positioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322519/how-do-i-center-vertically-and-horizontally-a-div-inside-the-body-element-withou)

Answer (score 2):

The styles defined for the body are set for a class, `.body { }`. this should just be `body { }` in your styling.

Comment: thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

First of all your `.Body` doesn't exist in html so either add this class to `<body>` element or change (as in my example) classname to tag.

this will make your `.grid-container` stay on center. However it will be less that few pixels wide. In order to prevent that youw will have to set `width` property to your `.grid-container` class something like `width: 500px` or make it more responsive and set `max-width: 500px; width: 100%;`

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    grid-gap: 2px;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    padding: 2px;
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}

.items {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 40px;
}

.item1 {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    background-color: orange;
}

.item2 {
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-column-end: 4;
    background-color: orange;
}

.item3 {
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 4;
    background-color: #dfe11b;
}

.item4,
.item5 {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 4;
    background-color: #e11b93;
}

.item6,
.item7,
.item8 {
    background-color: #0872d4;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="item1 items"></div>
    <div class="item2 items"></div>
    <div class="item3 items"></div>
    <div class="item4 items"></div>
    <div class="item5 items"></div>
    <div class="item6 items"></div>
    <div class="item7 items"></div>
    <div class="item8 items"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks dude it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

```css
.grid-container {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: auto auto                 
auto;
grid-gap: 10px;
background-color: #2196F3;
padding: 10px;
height:100vh;
width:100%;
background-color:#fff;
}

.items {
background-color: rgba(255, 255,     
255, 0.8);
text-align: center;
padding: 40px 0;




}

.item1 {
grid-column-start: 1;
grid-column-end: 3;
background-color: orange;
}
.item2{
grid-column-start: 3;
grid-column-end: 4;
background-color: orange;

}
.item3{
grid-row-start: 2;
grid-row-end: 4;
background-color:#dfe11b;
}

.item4{
grid-column-start: 2;
grid-column-end: 4;
background-color:#e11b93
}

.item5{
grid-column-start: 2;
grid-column-end: 4;
background-color:#e11b93
}

.item6{

background-color:#0872d4

}
.item7{

background-color:#0872d4
}

.item8{

background-color:#0872d4
}
body{
margin: 0;
padding:0;
box-sizing-border-box;**strong text**
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>grid</title>
</head>



<body>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1 items"></div>
  <div class="item2 items"></div>
  <div class="item3 items"></div>  
  <div class="item4 items"></div>
  <div class="item5 items"></div>
  <div class="item6 items"></div>
  <div class="item7 items"></div>
  <div class="item8 items"></div>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Add the height and width to the existing grid-container. Set the width to be 100% and for height to be 100vh, and it will be fullscreen. Set the margins and padding to 0 for the body to remove unwanted spaces.

And put the grid-gap to be wider, if you want it to be exactly the same as in the picture below.